# Generate HTML page with JS from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I'm looking for a very basic example of using Javascript to parse a JSON file and output an html file or populate an html file. All the examples I've located so far have code snippets and I don't have the background to fill in the blanks between.

Thank you for any fiddles (which would be awesome), links, and smart a*s comments.

Comment: You mean like `var data = JSON.parse('{"foo": "42"}'); document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.foo));` ? Parsing JSON is easy. You can add DOM elements using the appropriate methods (`createElement`, `appendChild`). Which elements have to be created and which data should be shown depends on what you want, there is no canonical answer for this. It might be even better for you to use templates.

Comment: Finally someone who's willing to *thank* me for a smart-ass comment, and I can't think of one!

Comment: Yes, except the JSON would be on the same server in its' own file.  I just found a fiddle for it I think.  http://jsfiddle.net/qmacro/NJMyD/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a microtemplating library, like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com), to parse incoming JSON objects into HTML snippets using `{{ key }}` template syntax. If your object looks like:

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'Joe Smith',
    age: 25,
    features: {
        hairColor: 'red',
        eyeColor: 'blue'
    }
};
```

Using Mustache, you can render it into HTML easily using {{#}} and {{/}} to traverse nested objects:

```
Mustache.render('Hello, my name is {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old. {{#features}} I have {{hairColor}} hair and {{eyeColor}} eyes.{{/features}}', myObj);
```

which outputs:

Hello, my name is Joe Smith and I am 25 years old. I have red hair and blue eyes.

EDIT: more germane application - dynamically generate a control panel using a template with nested lists of objects. Here's my template and object (HTML broken into a list and joined for clarity):

```
var panel = [
  '<div id="cpanel">',
    '{{#cpanel}}',
      '<div class="panel_section">',
        '<h1 class="cpanel">{{name}}</h1>',
        '<p>',
          '{{#content}}',
            '<button id="{{id}}">{{id}}</button>',
          '{{/content}}',
        '</p>',
      '</div>',
    '{{/cpanel}}',
  '</div>',
].join('\n');

var panelObj = {
  cpanel: [
  {
    name: 'playback',
    content: [
      {id: 'play'},
      {id: 'pause'},
      {id: 'stop'}
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'zoom',
    content: [
      {id: 'zoomIn'},
      {id: 'zoomOut'}
    ]
  }]
};
```

Then you render with Mustache:

```
Mustache.render(panel, panelObj);
```

which outputs:

```
<div id="cpanel">
  <div class="panel_section">
    <h1 class="cpanel">playback</h1>
    <p>
      <button id="play">play</button>
      <button id="pause">pause</button>
      <button id="stop">stop</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel_section">
    <h1 class="cpanel">zoom</h1>
    <p>
      <button id="zoomIn">zoomIn</button>
      <button id="zoomOut">zoomOut</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

### Templating example

I would suggest on of templating tools for example [PURE](https://pure-js.com/)...

The purpose of such a tool is separation of logic and representation.

For example, generating a list from JSON data using mentioned tool would look like this:

**JSON data file**

```
{'who':'BeeBole!'}
```

**HTML file**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>PURE Unobtrusive Rendering Engine</title>

  <script src="../libs/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/pure.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- the HTML template -->
  Hello <a class="who" href="#"></a>

  <script>
    // the JSON data we want to render
    $.getJSON('yourJSONdataFile.json', function(data) {
        // run the rendering
        $('a').autoRender(data);
        // PURE tries to match class with the JSON property and replace the node value with the value of the JSON property
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is most basic approach appropriate if you have simple JSON data (see working JSFiddle example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/47uQj/)).. [Get Started](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/get-started/) guide will walk you trough another example if basic approach isn't suitable. For more advanced features take look at the [documentation](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/).

### Alternatives

There was no particular reason that PURE has been used in above example. There are many other alternatives out there:

- [EJS](https://ejs.co)
- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Tempo](http://tempojs.com/)
- ...

...or you can do it manually as explained [there](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: is EJS dead or just the domain has been hijacked?

Comment: `PURE` and JSON Template, jQuote2 are broken too..

Comment: the **PURE** link at the top of the post is a 404 ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [jQuery.dForm](http://daffl.github.com/jquery.dform/#types/add-your-own). It helps creating HTML and forms dynamically using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

So i am assuming you mean your JSON contains the HTML string inside it.

lets say your JSON is:

```
{

"htmlString" : "<div> now thats smart! </div>"

}
```

you can render this in your HTML by writing your HTML as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    var myjson = {"htmlString" : "<div> now thats smart! </div>"}

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadHTML() {

    document.getElementByTagName("body").innerHTML(myjson["htmlString"]);

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload='loadHTML()'>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can also use AJAX to fetch your JSON and render it
however, note that embedding HTML inside JSON when transporting from server is considered a security vulnerability.
Instead, you can fetch a partial HTML from the server directly by using AJAX and then replace portions of that HTML (template) with dynamic values by using javascrip and REST/SOA

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Vijay.   I am probably not describing my question correctly.  I want to use a file of JSON data, grab it with javascript, and then format it with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

EJS or embedded java script which is nice and fun. You could use a front end framework like backbone or facebook's React which is allot more complex. There are some good video tutorials on codeschool's node lesson for EJS. here is an example

```
  var foo = {'city':'SF', 'party':'now'}
```

with EJS its as simple as:

```
   <div> <p> going to <%= foo.city %> to party <%= foo.party %> </p></div>
```

to get text:' going to SF to party now'

With EJS, or my fav PEJS you can do if, switch, for(), Date() ..... you get the point. look Here for [Pejs](https://github.com/mafintosh/pejs) and also read [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/). Lots of cool stuff you can do